# PHP Connection To MS SQL Server 2008 R2 Unsuccessful

Tags: php

### Using MS SQL Server 2008 R2:

```
<?PHP
    $servername = "";    //serverName\instanceName
//  $username = "";    // exclude UID, using windows authentication
//  $password = "";    // exclude PWD, using windows authentication
    $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"db.mdf");
    $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
    if( $conn ) {
         echo "Connection established.<br />";
    }else{
         echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }
?>
```

> Notice: Undefined variable: serverName in C:\OES\test.php on line 97 Call Stack: 0.0270 336232 1. {main}() C:\OES\test.php:0 Connection could not be established.

Please help me fix the connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Variable names in PHP are case sensitive

> Variables in PHP are represented by a dollar sign followed by the name of the variable. The variable name is case-sensitive.<sup>[1](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)</sup>

So change the variable name in either the first line or the 4th line to match the other:

```
$servername = "serverName\instanceName";    //serverName\instanceName
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($servername , $connectionInfo);
```

Also the database name sent to [sqlsrv_connect](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-connect.php) should not have the file name - remove the extension (i.e. *.mdf*):

```
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"my_db");
```

Comment: I made the two edits you suggested.  It replied "Connection established."  So I can only say awesome and thank you.